# match url params with regex

Tags: regex

Im trying to extract url params with regex.

here is an example string: `param1=val1&param2=val2&adv=val3&param3=val4&param4=val5`

This is the regex im using right now:

```
(\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

I can't figure out how to match the first param. I what to have param1 be in group 2 and val2 in group 3 like the rest of the param matches.

https://regex101.com/r/Qzxyyo/1

How can I do this?

edit:
So this seems to work (meaning param1 is in group 2 and val1 in is group3). But I dont understand why it works or if it is reliable:

```
(\&|^)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

Comment: First question: Why are you doing this? There's bound to be a library that parses these *correctly* for whatever language you're using.

Comment: using grok (logstash) and using a regex like this is the simplest way I can find

Comment: Do discussions [like this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/grok-uri-extract/54836/2) give any ideas? The `GREEDYDATA:uri_query` parser seems to do what you want.

Comment: tried that before with little success but I finally got it working. This was a regex question so Im marking to first answer correct but my specific logstash problem was solved with kv{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

Break it down!

1. `\&` look for a `&` character
2. `[^=]+` match characters up until it hits a `=`
3. `\=` match the `=` character
4. `[^&]+` match characters up until `&`
5. `()` These define the groups!